# Reducer Iterative context.write

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is it a best practice to write an output for each value iteration in Reducer's reduce method? Will it cause any bottleneck and cause performance degrading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is. Reducer's reduce method is designed for that. It will not cause any performance bottleneck. Although, you can break the code into small parts by following the Java coding standards for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Its also better to create the writable object once, at class level & change the contents of the object for every write, instead of creating new object for every iteration.